# How to detect when scrollbar hits bottom of modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scrollbar

I have a modal which I plan on dynamically placing content in when the scrollbar hits the bottom. Ive been doing much research and cant seem to find how I can detect when the modal scrollbar hits the bottom. What is supposed to happen is the alert will pop up stating the bottom has been reached.

**My code is below with a snippet:**

```js
$(".modal-body").scroll(function(){

    if($('#prev').height() == ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height())){
        alert("reached bottom!!")
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"style="height: 400px; overflow:auto;">
              <pre id="prev"style="display: inline-block; height: 900px"> </pre>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

as you can see, I cant seem to get it to detect the scrollbar hitting the bottom, Ive been at this for about an hour now. any help will be grateful!!

Comment: Try adding `position: fixed; overflow:hidden;` to the body when the modal is open? Although that may be worse for a11y

Comment: that doesnt seem to get the job done

Comment: (that's good it wasn't an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `position: absolute` to child then calculate the sizes for both parent and child with `getBoundingClientRect`, like so:

```js
$(".modal-body").scroll(function() {

  const modal = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  const prev = $('#prev')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  const modalTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle($(this)[0])['padding-top']);
  
  if (prev.top - modal.top === modalTop)
      alert("reached top!!")
  if ((modal.bottom | 0) === (prev.bottom | 0))
      alert("reached bottom!!")
});
```

```css
#prev {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"style="height: 400px; overflow:auto;">
              <pre id="prev" style="display: inline-block; height: 900px"> </pre>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: how can I also apply this to check if the top has been reached??

Comment: you should consider the `padding` of parent for this, so you can compute style on parent and make the diff like so: `prev.top - modal.top === parseInt(getComputedStyle($(this)[0])['padding-top'])`

Comment: I noticed that sometimes the "prev" value isnt always the same when the scrollbar hits  the bottom. at times the value is off by about 20px or so which doesn't register as it hitting the bottom. any clue as to why??

Comment: I noticed some strange behavior too, it seems to be because of `alert` box, with `console.log` everything goes fine on me

Comment: is there a reason when i scroll and hit the bottom it alerts twice?? as if it hit the bottom twice??